# priority-ionic: Click on form-list row not working on Android

Tags: debugging, apk

I am developing priority-ionic application in windows environment (Windows 7) using chrome.

On my home page I have form-list.When row of form-list is clicked I push next page(DetailPage) to NavController.

When I run the application by `ionic serve` all works as expected.

But in my Gallaxy 5 mobile phone (I have created apk file by `ionic cordova build  android` and installed it) when I press on row of form-list it is seems that nothing happened.

How can I check/fix/debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1) Make sure u have the latest version of [`priority-ionic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/priority-ionic) installed.

2) If still things are not working for u, just `npm install` from scratch.

3) About debugging the APK - there are many guides about this. Check this one out: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/. It doesn't have to be remote though.

You can find an excellent example of how to use `priority-ionic` here :  https://github.com/PrioritySoftware/app-master/